# Having multiple Unity Installations on multiple disks

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using a certain disk for my Unity installations. But for a specific version, I want to use another disk. Does changing the installation path on Unity Hub prevent me from using other versions or seeing installations on Hub? Or do I need to change the installation path everytime if I use a unity version from another disk?

Comment: no, it just tells it where to put any new version.. you can splatter them everywhere you like - although it may not enjoy changing modules if you havent them in one spot..

Comment: I think it is as @BugFinder says .. basically each install is more or less sandboxed. UnityHub just links them magically if installed through the Hub so you can afterwards add modules more easily ... you can do the same of course by just installing a version manually and add it to Hub manually .. but then you have to also install modules manually ;)

Comment: When I change the install location, Unity Hub can't open existing projects that opened with another unity version that installed another disk before.

Comment: It seems you need to change the installation folder every time you need a version on another path. Unity Hub just can't magically find installs and open projects.